# Unable to create DI for retrofit with Koin, android?

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, retrofit, koin

I am trying to have DI for creating a retrofit instance with KOIN
this is the module

```
val networkModule = module {
factory { provideRetrofit(get()) }
single { provideNetworkApi(get()) }
}

fun provideRetrofit(): Retrofit {
return Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(NetworkConstant.BASE_URL)
    .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
    .client(OkHttpClient.Builder().build())
    .build()

}

fun provideNetworkApi(retrofit: Retrofit): NetworkCall =
retrofit.create(NetworkCall::class.java)
```

In the application class

```
class BaseApp :Application() {

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    startKoin {
        androidLogger()
        androidContext(this@BaseApp)
        modules(listOf(prefModule,networkModule))
    }
}
}
```

The compiler is showing error on `provideRetrofit(get()`

```
Too many arguments for public fun provideRetrofit():
```

I was able to create DI for another class

```
val prefModule = module {
single { AppPreference(androidContext()) }
}
```

Can someone point me whats wrong here?

Comment: factory { provideRetrofit(get()) } in this , why get() is passed to function call ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Was being caused because of `get()`

```
val networkModule = module {
factory { provideRetrofit() }

single { provideNetworkApi(get()) }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would it be acceptable skip separation of `Retrofit` instance (what's benefit?) and simply combine it in the goal of creating your `NetworkCall`?

Here is an example of what I mean:

```
val appModule = module {
    single {
        val httpInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        httpInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)

        Retrofit.Builder()
            .client(
                OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .addInterceptor(httpInterceptor).build()
            )
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl("https://postman-echo.com/")
            .build()
            .create(PostmanEcho::class.java)
    }

    single {
        PostmanEchoRepository(get(), get())
    }
....
```

My `PostmanEchoRepository` is using equivalent of your `NetworkCall` as first param.

Details: https://github.com/oradkovsky/weird-data-input/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/ror/weirddatainput/di/AppModule.kt